# Apache + PHP creating a huge amount of sessions and eating away all inodes

Tags: apache-2.4

Last week I almost run out of inodes space (it had happened a few times before between a few months). After deleting all sessions older than 1 day (and recovering 80% of all / inodes) I set the php param `session.gc_maxlifetime` to 86400 thinking it would solve my problems.
But I was wrong, and today I ran out of free inodes because the huge amount of sessions. This simple does't make any sense. Our Apache httpd server barely receives 9 requests per second (zabbix statistics). After cleaning all sessions older than 1 day (again) I was left with 952946 (almost one million sessions younger than 24 hours).

Is there a way to discover what is creating so much sessions (I did not wrote the systems that run on that server)? Maybe some Apache statistics?

Comment: Can you have a chat with the software developer? It's going to be difficult or impossible for anyone else to figure out why the software is misbehaving.

Comment: Already did. But they are no the sharpest tools in the shelf. I am pretty sure that one of the 50 php scripts that run on cron has a insane loop that connects a few hundreds of times and for every connection creates a new session. But I really don't have time nor stomach to go over 300MB of very poorly written code. I was hoping that there was a way to keep track of the session creation without counting them so at less I can pinpoint when it get worse...

Comment: None of us have access to the code, so I'm not sure we can do anything at all.